# How to rearrange this equation to find the value of $L$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

This question has been difficult for me to answer for awhile. If anyone could help that would be great.

The period (the time for one complete swing back and forth) $p$, in seconds of a pendulum is related to its length, $L$, in metres, by the formula
$$p= 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
where $g= 9.8$ m/s. Rearrange the formula for $L$, and find the length needed for the pendulum to have a period of $1$ second.

I know that $L$ must be smaller than $1$, but I'm not sure how to rearrange the formula.

Comment: Do you mean $$p = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$? In that case, square both sides and multiply by $g/(4\pi^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$p=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
Divide both sides by $2\pi$: $$\frac{p}{2\pi} = \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$
Square both sides:$$\left(\frac{p}{2\pi}\right)^2 = \frac{L}{G}$$
Multiply both sides by $G$:
$$G \cdot \left(\frac{p}{2\pi}\right)^2 = L$$